# splitting date and time in data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, split, datetime-format

I have a column list of dates in data frame with date format `201001011200` as `%Y%m%d%H%M`. I wanted to split them as `%Y%m%d` and `%H%M` as Date and Time.

I tried to `as.Date(data$Date,origin = "1970-01-01")` but I got an error message

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

The class of the date is `numeric`. So I tried to convert it to `character`and applied the above `as.Date` function but was not helpful.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

EDIT

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Index Date          rank amount
81211 201004090000  11 4.9
81212 201004090100  11 4.6
81213 201004090200  11 3.3
81214 201004090300  11 2.7
81215 201004090400  11 3.1
81216 201004090500  11 3.7
81217 201004090600  11 4.0
81218 201004090700  11 4.2
81219 201004090800  11 4.2
81220 201004090900  11 4.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:** Beginning with your example data, you can do

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$Date), format =  "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

to change the column to a POSIX datetime value.  Then, to extract the date and time into two separate columns, you can do

```
data$date <- as.character(as.Date(data$Date))
data$time <- format(data$Date, "%T")
```

This gives the following updated data frame `data`

> ```
>    Index                Date rank amount       date     time
> 1  81211 2010-04-09 00:00:00   11    4.9 2010-04-09 00:00:00
> 2  81212 2010-04-09 01:00:00   11    4.6 2010-04-09 01:00:00
> 3  81213 2010-04-09 02:00:00   11    3.3 2010-04-09 02:00:00
> 4  81214 2010-04-09 03:00:00   11    2.7 2010-04-09 03:00:00
> 5  81215 2010-04-09 04:00:00   11    3.1 2010-04-09 04:00:00
> 6  81216 2010-04-09 05:00:00   11    3.7 2010-04-09 05:00:00
> 7  81217 2010-04-09 06:00:00   11    4.0 2010-04-09 06:00:00
> 8  81218 2010-04-09 07:00:00   11    4.2 2010-04-09 07:00:00
> 9  81219 2010-04-09 08:00:00   11    4.2 2010-04-09 08:00:00
> 10 81220 2010-04-09 09:00:00   11    4.0 2010-04-09 09:00:00
> ```

---

**Original Answer:** If you are starting with a numeric value, wrap it in `as.character()` then run it through `as.POSIXct()` to get a POSIX date-time value.

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$Date), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

As an example I will use `201001011200` as you gave.

```
(x <- as.POSIXct(as.character(201001011200), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M"))
# [1] "2010-01-01 12:00:00 PST"
```

Then to separate out the date and time you can do the following.

```
list(as.Date(x), format(x, "%T"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "2010-01-01"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "12:00:00"
```

That gives Date and character classed items, respectively.  For a plain old character vector, just use `format()` twice.

```
c(format(x, "%m-%d-%Y"), format(x, "%T"))
# [1] "01-01-2010" "12:00:00"
```

or

```
c(as.character(as.Date(x)), format(x, "%T"))
# [1] "2010-01-01" "12:00:00"
```

Comment: beat me to it .. the OP says they're starting with numeric, but they already know how to use `as.character()`, so your answer should get them the rest of the way ...

Comment: @ Richard Scriven The above date `201001011200` is just one of the dates in the column `Date`. The dates change by incrementing the hour. So, I have around 100K rows. The above solution didn't work.

Comment: I also used `data$Date<-as.POSIXct("data$Date",format="%Y%m%d%H%M")` , all the dates were changed to NA's

Comment: @RichardScriven your solution in the comment section worked fine. From that I used the following for splitting it in to Date and Time:       `data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)` 
  `data$Time <- format(data$Date,"%H:%M")` but as for the data frame for Time it only listed 0.00 for the whole column. why is that?

Comment: @RichardScriven why is `data$Time <- format(data$Date,"%H:%M")` is not working? I also tried with `data$Time <- format(data$Date,"%T") as per your above solution but it didn't work. It just displayed a column with no time in it.

Comment: @G1124E - I don't really know why that is.  It works fine when I run it on your example data.