# separating date and time column in data frame in r

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, tidyr

I am trying to separate my DATE column in my data frame which has the date stored as `%y%m%d %h%m%s` , however when I try to using the separate function, as well as following the instructions in the links below, I get NAs... How can I resolve this problem?

[r how to separate date time data types](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147063/r-how-to-separate-date-time-data-types/147070)

[splitting date and time in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034045/splitting-date-and-time-in-data-frame)

**Sample Data**

```
structure(list(STATION_NAME = c("PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", 
"PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", "PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", 
"PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", "PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", 
"PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", "PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", 
"PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", "PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US", 
"PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US"), DATE = structure(c(1262305260, 
1262305620, 1262307240, 1262314440, 1262328840, 1262332440, 1262336040, 
1262339640, 1262343240, 1262346840), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), HOURLYWETBULBTEMPF = c(33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 37L), HOURLYPrecip = c("0.01", "0.01", 
"0.02", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"
)), .Names = c("STATION_NAME", "DATE", "HOURLYWETBULBTEMPF", 
"HOURLYPrecip"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My attempts**

```
    philly_weather_data<-philly_weather_data%>%
      separate(DATE,into=c('DATE','TIME'),sep = '')

philly_weather_data$DATE <- as.POSIXct(as.character(philly_weather_data$DATE),
                                           format =  "%Y%m%d%H%M")

    philly_weather_data$DATE <- as.character(as.Date(philly_weather_data$DATE))
    philly_weather_data$TIME <- format(philly_weather_data$DATE, "%T")
```

Comment: Why not create a copy of the datetime column and then format the two separately - one to retain date part, while the other for the time part

Comment: `philly_weather_data %>% mutate(time = format(DATE, "%T"), date = as.Date(DATE))`?

Comment: @phiver That is exactly what I was looking for thanks! Question though.. Do you have any idea why the separate command didn't work?

Comment: @KWANGER - the `sep = ''` is looking for no space. Your code would work like this: `philly_weather_data %>% separate(as.character(DATE), into = c("Datepart", "Timepart"), sep = " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above and drawing from your own attempt, this line of code works:

```
philly_weather_data <- philly_weather_data %>% 
                       separate(as.character(DATE), into = c("Datepart", "Timepart"), sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `as.Date` with `format`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(DATE), times = format(DATE, "%H:%M:%S"))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   STATION_NAME             DATE                HOURLYWETBULBTE… HOURLYPrecip Date       times 
#   <chr>                    <dttm>                         <int> <chr>        <date>     <chr> 
# 1 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 00:21:00               33 0.01         2010-01-01 00:21…
# 2 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 00:27:00               33 0.01         2010-01-01 00:27…
# 3 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 00:54:00               33 0.02         2010-01-01 00:54…
# 4 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 02:54:00               34 0.00         2010-01-01 02:54…
# 5 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 06:54:00               34 0.00         2010-01-01 06:54…
# 6 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 07:54:00               34 0.00         2010-01-01 07:54…
# 7 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 08:54:00               34 0.00         2010-01-01 08:54…
# 8 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 09:54:00               34 0.00         2010-01-01 09:54…
# 9 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 10:54:00               35 0.00         2010-01-01 10:54…
#10 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIO… 2010-01-01 11:54:00               37 0.00         2010-01-01 11:54…
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option. Convert the `DATE` column and then use the `separate` function. You can convert the `DATE` to date class later.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.character(DATE)) %>%
  separate(DATE, into = c("DATE", "Time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE))
dat2
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#   STATION_NAME                             DATE       Time     HOURLYWETBULBTEMPF HOURLYPrecip
#   <chr>                                    <date>     <chr>                 <int> <chr>       
# 1 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 00:21:00                 33 0.01        
# 2 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 00:27:00                 33 0.01        
# 3 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 00:54:00                 33 0.02        
# 4 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 02:54:00                 34 0.00        
# 5 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 06:54:00                 34 0.00        
# 6 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 07:54:00                 34 0.00        
# 7 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 08:54:00                 34 0.00        
# 8 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 09:54:00                 34 0.00        
# 9 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 10:54:00                 35 0.00        
# 10 PHILADELPHIA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT PA US 2010-01-01 11:54:00                 37 0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `substr` instead:

```
philly_weather_data$TIME <- substr(philly_weather_data$DATE, 12, 20)
```

Comment: That works to create a new column for time but I also want to get ride of the time from the DATE column as well..

Comment: Then follow that with:

`philly_weather_data$DATE <- substr(philly_weather_data$DATE, 1, 10)`